# SSLHandshakeException when running on another thread on AWS Lambda (Java)

Tags: java, ssl, aws-lambda

I experience the following error when I make an api call from another thread on AWS Lambda, using Java.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:Remote host closed connection
> during Handshake

The code is fine when I run at local.
But when I run on AWS Lambda:

- If I run it on the main thread, the call is fine.
- If I run on the second thread without the api call, the program is fine as well.

I suspect the second thread of AWS Lambda may have some problem with the SSL set up.
Did any experience this? Hope can receive your sharing.

Comment: Can you provide some code ?

Answer (score 1):

Having multithreaded application running on a AWS lambda is not so recommended.

Here some more details what to expect
https://dzone.com/articles/multi-threaded-programming-with-aws-lambda